# Number Regular expression check fails

Tags: java, regex

I need to check for an expression which contains two digits a slash and three digits. I have coded the following test in Java:

```
String s="11/111";
System.out.println(s.matches("d{2}/d{3}"));
```

The method matches returns true if the RegEx is matched.However the check returns "false". What's wrong with my regular expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A digit is matched by `\d`, not `d`:

```
s.matches("\\d{2}/\\d{3}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget the backslash before `d`. It must be `\\d`, `d` alone would match a literal character `d`. Use `\\d` to match a digit character.

```
System.out.println(s.matches("\\d{2}/\\d{3}"));
```